# I am trying to print all pie charts for different types of attack labels but its only printing one?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, jupyter, data-analysis, intrusion-detection

```py
attacks=list(data.labels.unique())
for labe in attacks:
    print(labe)
    data.loc[data.labels=='normal']['protocol_type'].value_counts().plot(kind='pie', label=str(labe)+' protcol type proportions', autopct='%.2f%%')
```

[image]

I am trying to print all pie charts for different types of attack labels, but it's only printing one. How do I print all charts using loops?

Comment: when should I use a pie chart? Almost never.

Comment: You can create a figure with subplots: `fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=..., ncols=..., figsize=...)` and then `for ax, labe in zip(axs.flatten(), attacks)` with `......plot(..., ax=ax)`.